# How to 'fill' a mesh created from a sinle vertex correctly

Tags: uv

I have created a mesh object using the extrude 'tool' as follows  using default CUBE (which has the default material removed), merged at center (press M select merge at center) and then extruded along x and Y axis to create a multi-sided 'plane' which I then extrude on the Z axis to created 'thickness'. I then FILL the top and bottom 'faces' by selecting each edge in edit mode and then press F. When I add a material if I select just a color all faces are 'painted' with that color HOWEVER if I select Image texture it will not uv wrap. Am I using an incorrect method to fill?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your faces are properly marked as inside/outside.

You can do this by going to *Viewport Overlays > Face Orientation*, and recalculate it by going to *Edit Mode > Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Inside/Outside*. Also, make sure you apply any transformations using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>.

Alternatively, I achieved the same result as you by extruding along the Z axis AFTER pressing <kbd>F</kbd> to fill the face, which seem to play nicer with blender's UV wrapping.

P.S: Why are you using this roundabout way to create and extrude a face? If you're not specifically attached to the process, you can achieve the same result by scaling the default cube along the Z axis, or using the *Solidify* modifier on a plane.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply.  I did not think about using scaling on the Z axis NOT using the solidify modifier.  I have never used scaling in that manner before.  Also just before I noted your reply I considered that I should have Filled before extruding along the Z axis which I now think is more logical. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to 'tag' you in my first reply.  Well I still can't 'get it' so decided to recreate my 5 sided 'plane' as described in my question. That's where it seems to all fall over. I use edge select in edit mode and select all the edges (holding down the shift key) then press F to fill then use the extrude tool but regardless of selecting the Z axis it extrudes along another axis. How would you do it noting that my 'plane' has 5 unequal sides.  BTW why can't I tag you by starting my reply with @Onion-IO

Comment: I would recommend exiting edit mode, and using the "solidify" modifier to give Z axis width to your plane. Simply add the modifier under "generate" in the modifiers drop-down menu, and increase the "thickness" aspect

Comment: Thanks. I restarted and 'drew' my 5 sided 'plane' as before, filled the area then extruded on the Z axis. Still I was only able to add my texture image material to the top face but I added the side faces in edit model selecting the faces and then adding the material. All good now. I got there eventually even if not using a 'good' method.

Comment: @JohnArnold You cannot tag him because you comment on his answer. The author of a question/answer you comment on will automatically be notified. Only if there are several comments from different people tagging the author becomes available (if I remember correctly).

Comment: Thanks. It must be another forum I am using that requires @theirname to be entered so that they get advised of a reply. BTW am I supposed to be advised that there has been a response entered for me as all I ever get is a "Stack Overflow" email which usually comes MANY hours after a response has been entered.  What I do is to make a desktop shortcut of the url for my thread so that I can quickly check if there have been replies and which I often find there are well before the 'stack overflow' email.